# want to create a search bar like google in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar, searchbar

I have an array like ["apple","appear","Azhar","code","BCom"] etc. This array contain more than half a million of records.

Now what I want to do, is to place a `UISearchBar` like in google and then whenever user types a text, then the dropdown list would appear with all the results containing this text and user could select one from the list.

For example - if the user types "a", then "apple","appear" and "Azhar" would appear in a drop-down list.

I don't want to use a `UITableView` or anything else to load the records. Whenever user types any word it should collect records from the array and make a drop down to display them.

How can I do this? 
Suggestions required please.

Comment: _this array contain more then half million of records..._ I don't think this is the right approach for that goal

Comment: can you suggest something what is the batter way to do this

Comment: @NaqeebAhmed _what is the batter way to do this_ - To find a better approach, first you need to ask your self a few questions: (1) Do you really need such a big array? Think how much RAM you are wasting for those 500,000 strings. (2) How many filtered results should be shown? Note that in Google apps the results is usually limited to 5-10 results, which gives a lot better performance, then filtering all the array on every editing change event. (3) Note that your array is unsorted "code" before "BCom", "appear" before "Azhar", etc.. Using a sorted array for search, can improve performance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretty simple code that would do the trick, the search bar filter is easy, as for the drop down menu i use a third party Pod named 'DropDown' that is very easy to use : https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown

```
import UIKit
import DropDown

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

var data: [String] = ["apple","appear","Azhar","code","BCom"]
var dataFiltered: [String] = []
var dropButton = DropDown()

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataFiltered = data

    dropButton.anchorView = searchBar
    dropButton.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(dropButton.anchorView?.plainView.bounds.height)!)
    dropButton.backgroundColor = .white
    dropButton.direction = .bottom

    dropButton.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
        print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)") //Selected item: code at index: 0
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    dataFiltered = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter({ (dat) -> Bool in
        dat.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })

    dropButton.dataSource = dataFiltered
    dropButton.show()
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    for ob: UIView in ((searchBar.subviews[0] )).subviews {
        if let z = ob as? UIButton {
            let btn: UIButton = z
            btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchBar.text = ""
    dataFiltered = data
    dropButton.hide()
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Bro, love your answer, but you're missing searchBar.delegate = self inside didViewLoad() it will never execute if it is not for it

Comment: Not true, you can connect the delegate in the storyboard, which is what I normally do. No need to write unneeded code

Comment: Had i know that, been splitting my head for 3 days trying to get what you showed and trying other solutions, new to iOs programing btw

Comment: Haha sorry, at least you discovered something new

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved the app itself, Thanks again

Comment: The issue happening at my end is I cannot type text continuously & reload dropdown at same time. As I call showDropdown basically dropDown view is shown on top of my current view so to continue with searching again I have to dismiss Dropdown view , then only I am able to search again. Its nothing like google